# extract file from zip file in python

Tags: python

I have a zip file that contain many folders and each folder again contain many folders. I want to extract the specific file from the last folder in zip file and I need help to do that in python. the chart of zip file is:

zip file---(folder1, folder2, folder3)
-----folder1 (folder11,folder12)
---folder11(folder111)-----file1.kmz
-----folder2 (folder21,folder22)
---folder21(folder211)-----file2.kmz
-----folder3 (folder31,folder32)
---folder31(folder311)-----file3.kmz
I want to extract the file1.kmz, file2.kmz and file3.kmz in the single folder.

Comment: This would be easier as a command line.  `unzip -j xxx.zip *.kmz`.

Comment: From the description looks like file2.kmz is in folder211 not folder311 so it isn't in the last folder. If want to extract only from the last folder then only file3.kmz would be extracted from this example structure.

Comment: you right, it is not the last folder. each folder 111, folder 211 and folder 311 include a file.kmz (file1.kmz, file2.kmz,file3.kmz). I want to extract all kmz file from different folders.